# Extract form data from a Firefox profile database

Tags: firefox

I'm in the process of moving house. My desktop is currently working in headless mode. There isn't an X server and because it's all configured up for Nvidia, forwarding isn't working (missing NV extensions, etc).

I need to log into my online bank account but the only place that has the account number is Firefox on my desktop! It has saved it to the field and now I need to extract it somehow.

Does anybody know of what I'd need to get into it? Desperate times.

Comment: If it's possible to setup Firefox Sync in headless mode you might be able to sync from it. Just an idea.

Comment: Have you tried to to remotely login with `freenx`? I works also on headless machines.

Comment: Also, i would copy `.mozilla/firefox/*.default/formhistory.sqlite` and browse it with `sqlitebrowser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox form auto-completion database is a SQLite file. You'll need to install `sqlite3` in order to access such databases. After doing that, you can run a SQL query against the database (replace `PROFILE.NAME` accordingly):

```
sqlite3 -header -column ~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE.NAME/formhistory.sqlite 'SELECT fieldname, value FROM moz_formhistory'
```

You can limit the search to values containing "123" by appending `WHERE value LIKE "%123%"` after `moz_form_history`.

The password database gets more tricky as the contents of it are encrypted and therefore it's easier to start Firefox using the copied profile folder. Copy `~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE.NAME` from the remote side to the local side in `~/tmp-ff-prof` (tar + scp + tar). Then, run:

```
firefox -no-remote -profile ~/tmp-ff-prof &
```

`-no-remote` takes away the need for closing all Firefox instances.

You might also be interested in [Firefox Sync](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-firefox-sync) which allows you to share your passwords between profiles.

Comment: I didn't know you could subvert the profiles.ini like that. This makes it very easy to use a GVFS-mounted profile very temporarily - which is great for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One option (that I'm holding back from) is copying the whole profile out to this laptop and replacing the current one (after backing it up) and using it just like that.

I can't see why it wouldn't work but I've had some weird things happen when moving profiles around in Firefox before, hence me looking for a cleaner, remote option.

Comment: I think it should work.

Comment: It will work. Used Windows profile in Ubuntu before.